# exported fig and eps files are large in MATLAB 2015 and 2016

Tags: matlab, plot, eps, fig

I was creating and saving my plots using Matlab2014a before. Now, I updated my MATLAB version to 2015 (and 2016). When I ran my previous scripts using the new MATLAB, the figures (in both fig and eps formats) take 2-3 times more space than before. This is very problematic for me because using the new eps files in the latex leads to 3 times slow down in creating the final pdf.

Is there any way that I can create the plots using MATLAB2015 (or 2016) and get files with the same size as 2014a?

I have already checked the effect of changing Renderer, PaperPosition, resolution, and other properties of the figure, and none of them worked for me.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The issue is that the renderer is `opengl` by default on versions newer than R2014a. You can instead set it to `painters` prior to printing.

Comment: That was the first thing that I did. I changed the renderer to painters for both of them (2014a and 2015b). The sizes are completely different. Size of the files in MATLAB2015b are 2-3 times larger than MATLAB2014a

Comment: It's possible that there are just more elements in the EPS from the newer versions. A lot of things were changed with the introduction of HG2 in R2014b. The only "workaround" would be to open the plots in R2014a

Comment: My question is completely different from what you mentioned as duplicated. I have used the same parameters (fig properties) in both 2014a and 2015b.

Comment: There exists a way to post-process the .eps files automatically using InkScape + python. See a discussion on the topic [here](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/44#issuecomment-267713354).

Comment: @Ramin Right, that's why I re-opened it.